# How can I use IDLE() method to check for new mails from the server using IMAP in Python?

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I wrote the code to read mails from the server using IMAP in python. I have to run the program at each time to get the new mails. Hence  I went through several tutorials [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659334/getting-email-message-after-imap-idle-command-exists-response), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086465/python-keep-checking-new-email-and-alert-of-further-new-emails), where I found that **While loop** and **idle()** method can be used for this process. I know how to use while loop for this purpose.

```
while True:
    mail.select("Inbox")
    ##some data
     time.sleep(120)
```

Now want to use **idle()** method for the same purpose. How can do this ?

Comment: You'll need a different library.  imaplib doesn't support idle.

Comment: Relevant: [idle_example.py](https://github.com/mjs/imapclient/blob/master/examples/idle_example.py) and [Using IMAP IDLE to Wait for Updates](https://www.example-code.com/python/imap_idle.asp)